# Selenium how to locate element by partial By.Name (in C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a function to locate an element by *Partial* match on "**By.Name**". But I cannot make it working.

I have tried different permutations of regex (as I found it on internet), but not of those works. 
I.e. this one will not find the element:

```
*var element = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-container")).First()
                .FindElement(By.Name("//*[contains('Price')]"));*
```

And this one will throw compilation error:

```
*var element = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-container")).First()
                .FindElement(By.Name([*='Price']));*
```

If I specify exact match it works fine:

```
*var element = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-container")).First()
                .FindElement(By.Name("RegularPrice"));*
```

Here is my html page:

```
<tbody class=”x-container”> <tr class="first-row">    <td class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control x-name">
      <span data-validation-for="Name" class="help-block hidden"></span>    </td>    <td class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="Color" class="form-control x-color-dropdown" disabled="">    </td>    <td class="has-btn-copy-link">
      <input type="number" name="RegularPrice" class="form-control">
      <a data-field="RegularPrice" class="btn btn-link btn-copy-field x-copy-to-all">Copy to all</a>    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because By.Name doesn't allow partial matching--only whole matches**

The first example is using xpath notation, and I believe the second is CSS. You cannot mix and match these things.

Unless there is a pressing need for you to use By.Name, just switch to By.xpath

```
*var element = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-container")).First()
            .FindElement(By.Xpath("./*[contains(@name,'Price')]"));*
```

*Note: I am not a C# programmer, so the syntax may not be quite right. I'm basing it off my Java experience*

Comment: Thanks @MivaScott, here is the C# syntax, and it works! I guess I do not have to use By.Name, and can replace By.XPath  *var element = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-container")).First()
                .FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@name,'Price')]"));*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in earlier answers - `By.Name` allows **only a whole match case**.

Here's how whould you locate this element using `By.Xpath`:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//*[@class='x-container'])/*[contains(@name,'Price')]"));
```

And you can also use `By.CssSelector`:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".x-container > [name*='Price']"));
```

In this example you don't need to find all elements and use `.First` -
Since this is a combination of both parent and child elements, and by default you'll get the first match that being found.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a partial match using `By.Name()` but you can do it using CSS selectors or XPath. Looking at your code, there are a couple things I would change:

1. When you use `.FindElements(locator).First()` you are finding all elements that match `locator` and then picking the first one... which you probably knew. Since you are just picking the first, you can replace this code with `.FindElement()`. It will return only the first match, no matter how many matches there are.
2. You are chaining `.FindElement/s()` calls together. Each time you call find, you are scraping the page. When possible, you should combine locators into a single locator that will find the element(s) you want. In this case, it's pretty simple. We can use a CSS selector:

   ```
   .x-container [name*='Price']
   ```
3. `.FindElement()` returns a web element, `IWebElement` type. You should specify this instead of using `var`.

You can package this all up into the code below

```
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".x-container [name*='Price']"));
```

This will accomplish what you asked and only scraping the page once.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC! That looks quite neat and clean. And works too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for your needs but I solved a similar issue (where the start of the input or text area changed but the end was always the same.

ie: ada5120d-d018-4d16-9a3c-a18c7a0bdb67_txtDHFirstName

To solve this issue I created this helper where I get a list of all the input/textarea elements and loop through them looking for the name I passed.  It first looks for input controls then textarea elements if it didn't find anything in the input controls.  You could change the "endswith" to "contains" if it wasn't the end that you were looking for.  Hope it helps :)

```
List<IWebElement> eles = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input")).ToList();
foreach (IWebElement ele in eles)
{
    string eleName = ele.GetAttribute("name");
    if (eleName.EndsWith(name))
    {
        if (ele.Displayed)
        {
            ele.Clear();
            ele.SendKeys(value);
            valueSet = true;
        }
    }
}

if (!valueSet)
{
    eles = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("textarea")).ToList();
    foreach (IWebElement ele in eles)
    {
        string eleName = ele.GetAttribute("name");
        if (eleName.EndsWith(name))
        {
            if (ele.Displayed)
            {
                ele.Clear();
                ele.SendKeys(value);
                valueSet = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```